# Самый быстрый способ отфильтровать одинаковые значения в массиве?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Самое главное скорость выполнения.
Есть массив значений. Нужно из массива удалить одинаковые значения
но кроме значения value, оно может отличаться. Если все поля в объекте кроме value совпадают то элемент должен быть удалён(либо помещен в другой массив).
Я реализовал алгоритм двойного цикла с проверкой каждого с каждым элемента. Но при очень больших значениях начинаются тормоза.
Например при 250000 записей цикл пробегает 62 500 000 000 раз.
Есть ли возможность переписать алгоритм чтобы он отрабатывал быстрее?

```
 let streamsTDData_ = [{
      'tup': '111',
      'color': 'RED',
      'value': 12,
    },
    {
      'tup': '111',
      'color': 'RED',
      'value': 13,
    }, {
      'tup': '111',
      'color': 'RED',
      'time': '2019',
      'value': 13,
    }, {
      'tup': '112',
      'color': 'RED',
      'value': 213,
    }];
```

Comment: отсортировать по кастомной функции сравнения, а затем за один проход удалить совпадения

Comment: @manking Вопрос не в тему, но меня очень интересует - кто/что вас заставило фильтровать 250k вельюев JSом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть чуть пошустрее работать так как применяеться оптимизация алгоритма hashmap для поиска по ключу в ассоциативном массиве.
По крайней мере минтетический тест отрабатывает достаточно шустро.

```
function uniq(list) {
    var byUniq = list.reduce(function(map, obj) {
        map[obj.tup + obj.color + obj.time] = obj;
        return map;
    }, {});
    var result = [];
    for ( var item in byUniq ){
        result.push( byUniq[ item ] );
    }
    console.log(result.length);
    return result;
}

var bigData = []
for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    bigData.push({
        'tup': '111' + (i%20),
        'color': 'RED',
        'value': 12 + i,
    });
    bigData.push({
        'tup': '111' + (i%20),
        'color': 'RED',
        'value': 13 + i,
    });
    bigData.push({
        'tup': '111' + (i%20),
        'color': 'RED',
        'time': '2019',
        'value': 13 + i,
    });
    bigData.push({
        'tup': '112' + (i%20),
        'color': 'RED',
        'value': 213 + i,
    });
}

uniq(bigData);
```

Comment: Да, на порядок быстрее отрабатывает, спасибо!